# How to add fast lane tools in VSTS for Xamarin iOS and Android deployment

Tags: xamarin, release-management, fastlane, fastlane-deliver, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to automate the release for my xamarin iOS and android apps into the stores. I was wondering, if I can use fast lane tools via VSTS to do it.

Right now I directly add the playstore step in VSTS to deploy the android app into playstore. But, I want to make use of snapshot,snap grab, spaceship, supply and various other fastlane tools. Is it possible? If yes can anyone provide steps of how to do it? I tried searching the marketplace in vsts but the fastlane tools are not available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, VSTS released extensions to release iOS app on App Store or test flights.

[Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.app-store)

Answer (score 2):

> Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and Team Foundation
>   Server (TFS) use fastlane in their [Apple App Store extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.app-store).
>
> **Getting Started**
>
> Once you have created or retrieved credentials for
>   your App Store account, then perform the following steps to automate
>   releasing updates from a VSTS build or release definition:
>
> 1. Install the App Store extension from the VSTS Marketplace
> 2. Go to your VSTS or TFS project, click on the **Build** tab, and create a new build
>      definition (the "+" icon) that is hooked up to your project's appropriate
>      source repo
> 3. Click **Add build step...** and select the
>      necessary tasks to generate your release assets (e.g. Gulp, Cordova
>      Build)
> 4. Click **Add build step...** and select App Store Release from the
>      **Deploy** category
> 5. Configure the **App Store Release** task with the desired
>      authentication method, the generated IPA file path, and the desired
>      release track.
>
> Now when you build, your app will automatically be
>   published to *iTunes Connect*!

[Fastlane Docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/#visual-studio-team-services)